# How to combat journal spam: unit-specific MaxLevel* settings?

Tags: systemd, journald

I know about `MaxLevelStore`, `MaxLevelSyslog`, `MaxLevelKMsg`, `MaxLevelConsole`, `MaxLevelWall` but the problem with them is, they affect all units. Trouble is, not all developers *cough* kde *cough* gtk *cough* understand the difference between a warning and a debug.

Hence I need different settings for different units. I have read the man pages, arch/gentoo wikis, and it seems to me that such a simple concept does not exist :S

Answer (score 2):

There are tasks in TODO list (https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/afc402b76a4520997a7c831a943be75e3072b301/TODO) related to per service logging. No one had time to implement them so far.

Comment: Could you adjust the link to point to the exact line(s) via `#L{StartNo}[,L{EndNo}]` syntax? Do you mean `journald: allow per-priority and per-service retention times when rotating/vacuuming`?

Comment: Yes that is the item.